# how to close an android application after exception caught

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am designing an Android Application where i want to check details if crash happens. So i used Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() Class. It generate detail of Crashed Thread but Application Stuck once crash occur. I want to close my application immediately after crash but also want to detail of Thread. I include following code in the Activity class. Any suggestion?

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                Log.e("UserApp", "uncaught_exception_handler: uncaught exception in thread " + thread.getName(), ex);


                if(ex instanceof RuntimeException)
                    throw (RuntimeException)ex;
                if(ex instanceof Error)
                    throw (Error)ex;


                Log.e("UserApp", "uncaught_exception handler: unable to rethrow checked exception");

            }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `finish()` and `System.exit(1)` on the main/launcher Activity after processing the Exception?

Comment: @grizzly Use both methods but still the same problem.It shows logs but doesn't close the application

Comment: Is there an error or any interesting message in the LogCat window about why are these failing? This should work IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try `finish();` in your `exception` block

Comment: its not working. My application still stuck after using this method

Comment: finish() can't be called from the Application class where the UnCaughtException handler is defined

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

You can use,

```
YourActivityname.this.finish();     or

android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.myPid());
```

You should use first one because it is a best practice, which is to just call finish() and let the OS take care of killing off your process when/if it needs to.

In spite of if you use [second one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html), kill your process in the middle of event handling, all kinds of bad things -it is a bad practice.